# Nodeclipse : Unable to run even the simplest app

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I have an issue with nodeclipse: I am unable to run even the simplest demo app (simple require http). When I try to run my "app.js" as a node application, I am just getting:

```
<terminated, exit value: -1073741819>Node.js Process
```

When I try to run from the command prompt `node app.js`, everything goes fine. Did I forget anything important ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is some additionnal informations:

- Env config: Win 8 64 bits + Eclipse Kepler 64 bits (JRE 6.0.390.4)
- Enide from Eclipse marketplace (based on Nodeclipse 0.9.05)
- NodeJs v 0.10.24

Comment: You should give information about OS, Java, Eclipse, Nodeclipse versions.

Comment: @PaulVerest I have added some details in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this problem arise from time to time, the exact cause is not yet known. More feedback is needed.
(Once the problem goes away there is no way to reproduce healing; so the only way is to collect data in what environment, and how was solved)

Check [Nodeclipse Online Help - Run page](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/run.md#running)

There are 2 similar issues raised before.

- #72, [#176](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/176) was solved via Java upgrade to 1.7
- #107 was solved via running `node --debug-brk app.js` from console first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try tonight to upgrade to 1.7 and put an update!

Comment: I have uninstalled nodeclipse, updated to 1.7.0_51 and reinstalled nodeclipse. The problem seems to be solved with this new configuration.

Comment: I feel like updating Java would be enough, but I have such PC to try.

Comment: I am having the same problem on mac Yosemite 10.10.4 + eclipse mars 4.5.0 + Nodeclipse plugin 1.0.2 + node v0.12.7

Comment: Please raise issue on GitHub, Stackoverflow is not bug tracker